# Center a V3 Google Map on route after directions are rendered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a V3 map loading and centering on a particular longitude/latitude by default.  Once loaded, the user can enter their address to get directions to that point.  When this happens, the map is resized to accomodate a directions box to its left.  Because of this, the route is off-center in the map window.  I tried the following code, which I thought should logically work, but to no avail.

**New realization:** If I resize the window in any way, it begins to work as expected.

**Found the issue:** I needed to trigger `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` after I resize the map container.

```
directionsService.route(query, function(result,status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        // This sets the directions container to display:block and resizes the map
        document.getElementById('map-container').className = "directions";
        directions.setDirections(result);
        var bounds = result.routes[0].bounds;
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    } else {
        alert("");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2018-05-22**

With a new renderer release in version 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API the resize event is no longer a part of `Map` class.

The documentation states

> When the map is resized, the map center is fixed
>
> - The full-screen control now preserves center.
> - **There is no longer any need to trigger the resize event manually.**

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` doesn't have any effect starting from version 3.32

Comment: once you call fitBounds it should center based off LatLngBounds so you shouldn't need to setCenter

Comment: Yeah, I added setCenter() in a last ditch effort.  It doesn't get centered as expected with or without it.

Comment: totally misread the "resize" map part. glad it worked out

Comment: @Justin Can you please answer your own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've already found the answer I was coming to say. The resize event is very important to get right anytime you change the map container (or possibly its parent). In my case, I was flipping between two tabs (map and driving directions). At first the map would appear correctly in the map tab, but switching to the directions and back to the map caused display funkiness.

If your map is only showing a small tile in one corner (upper left in my case) with the rest blank chances are you need to fire the resize trigger.